# Does xs:time default to UTC when time zone is omitted?

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd

The [XML schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) seems vague on how to interpret an xs:time value when no time zone is specified. (See [section 3.2.8](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#time).) Is there a common consensus on this (e.g. UTC or the local time zone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got close to the right point in the spec. See slightly above, under [dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime):

> "Local" or untimezoned times are presumed to be the time in the timezone of some unspecified locality as prescribed by the appropriate legal authority;

Most systems I have dealt with make the local time assumption.

Comment: "some unspecified locality as prescribed by the appropriate legal authority" - I suppose this does imply some local time zone.

I was asking specifically about xs:time, but given the vagueness of the spec for this data type I suppose it's reasonable to take a steer from xs:dateTime.